# How to split a long hex string

Tags: unix, vim

I've a long hex string
00121eafc5800020 ... etc.

Is there an easy way I can split these with a space per hex coded byte so I get 
00 12 1e af c5 80 00 20 in vim (or another easily accessible tool)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/\(..\)/\1 /g' <<< '1234567890'
12 34 56 78 90
```

Comment: Same command works in vim too, just add a line number, a range, or a % in front of it as appropriate.   (Uh, I'll mention that you should remove the 'sed' bit... just in case, I've seen some impressive people here.)

Comment: Which is equivalent to `s/../& /g`

Comment: note that the /g at the end will dice up everything on the given line.

Comment: How does that regular expression work?

Comment: It puts 2 characters in group 1, then outputs group 1 with a space after it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this key sequence (from the start of the number):
    `q1lxPpr lq@1@1@1@1@1@1@1@1` (etc. or say, 20@1)

Comment: "Try this key sequence" without any explanation is never a good answer to vim questions.

Comment: Maybe. But that would spoil the fun of finding out.

Comment: Last I checked, *this site* was where people went for good answers.

Comment: I agree. This is a good answer. You'll note the (also good) accepted answer is also pretty terse. If you want to edit both to add a wordy explanation you are welcome to. Alternatively you can trust that the average reader knows enough to lookup the details to sed regex or the vim key map.

Answer (score 0):

In `vim`, you can use `:s/\([0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)/\1 /g` to do what you want. To test this, you can use the following command:

```
dd bs=512 if=/dev/urandom count=2 2>/dev/null | xxd -p | tr -d '\n' | vim -
```

Then in `vim`, use `:s/\([0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)/\1 /g` to add a space after every pair of hex-characters. Here's a small example:

```
$ dd bs=32 if=/dev/urandom count=1 2>/dev/null | xxd -p | tr -d '\n' | vim -
6aad5f800a739fadbc3e2312230daeca8055491577b0e0d75a37bb3777f0a3e0
:s/\([0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)/\1 /g
6a ad 5f 80 0a 73 9f ad bc 3e 23 12 23 0d ae ca 80 55 49 15 77 b0 e0 d7 5a 37 bb 37 77 f0 a3 e0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/\x\x/& /g
```

is enough.

If you want to cut into several lines, you can also apply this `:substitute` first.

```
:%s/\x\{16}/&\r/g
```

Or if you prefer a one-liner (I'm not sure this is a better solution here)

```
:%s/\x\{16}/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\x\x', '& ', 'g')."\n"/g
```